# How to access specific web element Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to click on an element that is on a website. I don't know why my script doesn't see the element. I have it running and when I use Python Shell and write:

```
z = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='0_40']")
```

I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='0_40']"}
```

I know that element exists because when I go to Console and put:

```
$$("input[name='0_40']")
```

I get:

```
[input#C0_40.textfield]
0
:
input#C0_40.textfield
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

This is the elements website location (element at the end):

```
<html>
<body class="tebody" onload="javascript:CARO.caroInit();" onresize="javascript:CARO.onResize();">
<div id=”normMenu”>
<div id=”caroHolder” style=”top: 81px;”>
<div id="e1AppFrameContainer" class="caroLeft caroExpanded" tilesize="small" whichcaption="label_two_rows">
<div id="outerRCUX">
<div id="innerRCUX">
<iframe id="e1menuAppIframe" name="e1menuAppIframe" title="e1menuAppIframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="/jde/Welcome.mafService?e1.state=maximized&amp;e1.service=Welcome&amp;E1CurrentWindowName=E1MENUMAIN_8595835811943006208&amp;RENDER_MAFLET=E1Menu&amp;e1.namespace=&amp;namespace=&amp;e1.mode=view">
<html>
<body>
<form style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" action="javascript:void(0);" id="E1PaneForm" name="P43070_W43070A" method="post">
<div id="e1formDiv" tabindex="-1" onscroll="FormDivScrollHandler.syncToolBar(true)" class="formdiv_noIE e1container" style="height: 570px; width: 768px;">
<table width="100%" id="FormAboveGridTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;"><tbody><tr><td>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="position: relative; width: 744px; height: 367px;" id="FormAboveGrid" onkeydown="return FormKeyboardHandler.onContainerKeyDown(event,'0')" onmousedown="return true;" oncontextmenu="return FormKeyboardHandler.formExitContextMenu(event)">
<span id="outer0_45" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; top: 3px; width: 722px;" hasadjacentcontrols="true" shouldelongate="true">
<table class="GroupBox" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1"><tbody><tr><td height="182" valign="TOP" class="ClearBorders">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="182" valign="TOP" class="ClearBorders">
<div style="position: relative; width: 722px; height: 182px;" id="div0_45" onkeydown="return FormKeyboardHandler.onContainerKeyDown(event,'0_45')" onmousedown="return true;" oncontextmenu="return FormKeyboardHandler.formExitContextMenu(event)">
<span id="outer0_40" style="position:absolute; left: 151px;  top: 3px;  width:135px; ">
<nobr>
<input class="textfield" type="text" name="0_40" title="Branch/Plant" maxlength="12" value="*" style="vertical-align: top; width: 118px; cursor: auto;" onhelp="hp('0_40')" onmouseover="updateHelpCursor('',this)" tabindex="7" id="C0_40" htmlpostflag="false" onfocus="FCHandler.onFocusVA(this,'',false)" onkeydown="FCHandler.onKeyDownTextField(this,'','3', event,false,'UTC')" onmousedown="FCHandler.onKeyDownTextField(this,'','3', event)" onblur="FCHandler.onExitVA(this,false,'',false)">
```

I suspect that script cannot locate the element because it is generated by JavaScript, but when I use:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",z);
```

I doesn't work either. 
Is it possible to locate and click this element? What am I doing wrong? Big thank you for everyone who is going to spend his/her time trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Before I investigate further have you tried accessing the element using the following? //element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
//element = driver.find_element_by_id("html ID name")
//element = driver.find_element_by_name("html element name")
//element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwd-id']")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If element generated by JavaScript it doesn't mean that you can handle it with `execute_script()` only. It mean that you might need some time until JavaScript executed and element appeared in DOM.

Note that element is located inside an iframe, so you need to switch to iframe before locating input field

Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("e1menuAppIframe"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "0_40"))).send_keys("text to send")
```

Comment: Problem solved. Once again- thx you very much. I didn't know that there is such a thing as iframe.